# Developing AR app to visualise data possible

Tags: android-studio, project, augmented-reality

I'm looking into Augmented Reality now as part of a project and I have an idea to visualise datasets into their retrospective 3d models. E.g. I point the scanner at a image of a bar chart and a bar chart representing the data will appear. I was wondering if anyone has done something like this with AR? Googling has been fruitless, I would be trying to do this in android studio with Arcore if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called an "Image Target Tracking." There are many different ways you can go about achieving this effect. I would recommend looking into Vuforia library for Unity, as it is probably one of the most user-friendly cross-platform solutions:
https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Image-Target-Guide

If you wish to use ARcore, there's documentation on that here:
https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/augmented-images/

Another cool platform, that is probably even easier to use than either of the above is FaceBook's AR Studio, although this means that the effect will only be viewable through the Facebook App, which has it's own pros and cons. Here's a good tutorial for that:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ar-studio/docs/plane-tracker/

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!